# Tiny utility decoding base64-encoded file names

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, base64, text-parsing

For convenience and speed of debugging my `R` code, I decided to create a tiny `AWK` script. All it has to do is to decode all base64-encoded names of files (`.RData`) in a particular directory. I've tried my best in two attempts. The following are my results so far. Any help will be appreciated!

**The first attempt** is an `AWK` script *embedded* in a `shell` command:

```
ls -1 ../cache/SourceForge | awk 'BEGIN {FS="."; print ""} {printf("%s", $1); printf("%s", " -> "); print $1 | "base64 -d -"; print ""} END {print ""}'
```

The *resulting output* is **close** to what is needed, however, instead of printing each decoded filename on the same line with the original encoded one, this one-liner prints all decoded names in the end of processing with no output separator at all:

```
cHJqTGljZW5zZQ== ->
cHViUm9hZG1hcA== ->
dG90YWxEZXZz ->
dG90YWxQcm9qZWN0cw== ->
QWxsUHJvamVjdHM= ->
Y29udHJpYlBlb3BsZQ== ->
Y29udHJpYlByb2Nlc3M= ->
ZG1Qcm9jZXNz ->
ZGV2TGlua3M= ->
ZGV2U3VwcG9ydA== ->

prjLicensepubRoadmaptotalDevstotalProjectsAllProjectscontribPeoplecontribProcessdmProcessdevLinksdevSupport
```

**The second attempt** is the following *self-contained* `AWK` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {FS="."; print ""; files = "ls -1 ../cache/SourceForge"}
{
  decode = "base64 -d -";
  printf("%s", $1); printf("%s", " -> "); print $1 | decode; print ""
}
END {print ""}
```

However, this script's *behavior* is **surprising** in that, firstly, it awaits for input, and, secondly, upon receiving `EOF` (`Ctrl-D`), doesn't produce any output.

Comment: I don't care about my rating, but just curious why a downvote. Care to explain?

Comment: It wasn't me, but I had to wonder why you didn't just ask "This prints `foo bar 8`. Why isn't it `foo 4 bar 4`?  `printf "foo\nbar\n" | awk '{ print $1; print $1 | "wc -c"; }'`"

Comment: @thatotherguy: Thanks for the comment! While some people prefer brevity, others prefer understanding context, which frequently contains essential details and, therefore, is important. I believe that every person is unique and, thus, has her/his own style of asking questions, presenting information, etc. I don't think that an individual style of doing things should be looked at as if it has less value.

Comment: Examples should be [small, self contained and correct](http://www.sscce.org/). Requiring people to have a sourceforge cache directory to reproduce the problem is not a matter of personal style.

Comment: @thatotherguy: I'm aware of reproducibility. However, you completely didn't understand my question, if you've said what you've said. My reference to SourceForge is purely contextual and in no way is preventing people, who understood my question, to reproduce my scenario. The essence of my question is in the second sentence, which clearly declares its generic nature.

Comment: I'm only volunteering this point of view because you asked, "Care to explain?" and the downvoter didn't say. I didn't think the question deserved a downvote, but I did think that the cognitive burden on me as a reader was significantly higher than necessary. If you believe your question expresses a general problem in a simple, direct and relatable way, that's fine.

Comment: @thatotherguy: I understand. Thank you for expressing your point of view. As I said, it's also a matter of personal tolerance (and value) for the amount of context surrounding core information. For one the context is a distraction, for another - it's valuable element for better understanding of the subject. Thanks again and best wishes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mostly bash solution:

```
for f in ../cache/SourceForge/*; do
  base=$(basename $f .RData)
  echo "$base => $(base64 -d <<<$base)"
done
```

Or, using more bash:

```
for f in ../cache/SourceForge/*; do
  f=${f##*/}; f=${f%%.*}
  echo "$f => $(base64 -d <<<$f)"
done
```

In both cases, you could use `../cache/SourceForge/*.RData` to be more specific about which filenames you want. In the second one, using `f=${f%.*}` will cause only one extension to be removed. Or `f=${f%.RData}` will cause only the `.RData` extension to be removed. But it probably makes little difference in that specific application.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! While I preferred an `AWK` solution, this is also very nice (and practical). I appreciate another opportunity to learn a bit more of `Unix` shell programming! :-) As other answers (as of now) don't provide a complete and correct solution, I will gladly accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the process you are writing to between each line or awk sends all the printed lines to the same process (and it only prints output when it finishes I guess). Add `close("base64 -d -")` to the end of that action block (same exact command string). For example:

```
ls | awk -F. '{ printf("%25s -> ", $1); print $1 | "base64 -d -"; close("base64 -d -"); print "" }'
```

Your second snippet isn't running that `ls` command. It is just assigning it to a variable and doing nothing with that. You need to pipe the output from `ls` to `awk -f <yourscript>` or `./your-script.awk` or similar to get it to work. (This is why it is waiting for input from you by the way, you haven't given it any.)

To actually run the ls from awk you need to use [getline](http://awk.info/?tip/getline).

Something like `awk 'BEGIN {while ( ("ls -1" | getline) > 0 ) {print}}'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just tried to add `close` per your advice (as a third line in the block), but it didn't work. I tried both exact command line (`close("base64 -d -")`) and a variable reference (`close(decode)`).

Comment: You tried it in the second snippet? I was testing with the first but the premise is the same. I should mention that in testing this here I was getting errors from base64 about bad input (though I was also getting correct decoded output).

Comment: Yes, I tried it in the second snippet. I'm not sure where would the bad input messages come from. The test directory should contain files, named per format `<base64-encoded string>.RData`.

Comment: I don't have your data clearly I was testing on my own. I think that's just a quirk of my base64 binary and the way the pipe is being used in awk. I just figured to mention it in case. My edit about your second snippet and the `ls` command is the reason behind that snippet not working at all for you.

Comment: But, how to invoke `ls` command from withing AWK script (similarly to `base64`) and use its output for further processing? I want the utility to be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: Just saw your update on `getline`. I was reading on it, too, but still trying to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: you need to run close right after the pipe, i.e. in the first attempt use this: `...; print $1 | "base64 -d -"; close("base64 -d -"); ...;`.

Comment: @Thor: Thank you! I tried that, but it still doesn't work - probably my use of double piping via `decode`: `ls -1 <dir> | awk 'BEGIN {FS="."; print ""} {printf("%s", $1); printf("%s", " -> "); decode = print $1 | "base64 -d -"; close("base64 -d -"); decode | getline name; print name} END {print ""}'`. Thanks to @rici, I already have a nice bash solution, but I'm still curious about fixing my `AWK` attempt...

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: here is a code block that works here: `{ printf("%25s -> ", $1); print $1 | "base64 -d -"; close("base64 -d -"); print "" }`.

Comment: @Thor: Great! It does work, indeed. I was pretty close, but deviated toward over-complicating the solution by wanting to create a self-contained script. I appreciate your advice! P.S. If you'd like, you can post your solution as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: Etan already suggested so I added the code snippet to his answer.

Comment: @Thor: Fair enough. Thank you again! I'd appreciate if you could update your snippet in the answer: it should be `ls -1` for the script to work correctly, using just `ls` produces output in matrix format by default (at least, in my environment), which causes incorrect parsing.

Comment: I just benchmarked both solutions out of curiosity. It's interesting that the AWK solution is almost 30% faster than the bash one. For my scenario the difference is negligible in absolute numbers, but for big data the performance gain could be significant. Just some food for thought.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: When `ls`'s output is connected to a pipe `ls -1` is the default, see for example `ls | cat`.

Comment: @Thor: You're right, sorry about misunderstanding. The problem was related to running the script in the wrong directory with different content. Again, my apologies!

Answer (score 2):

```
while read
do
  base64 -d <<< $REPLY
  echo
done < infile.txt
```

Result

```
prjLicense
pubRoadmap
totalDevs
totalProjects
AllProjects
contribPeople
contribProcess
dmProcess
devLinks
devSupport
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't want to deal with extra files - I'd like to use pipes to send `ls -1 <dir>` output directly to the processing part (preferably, within the utility's body, as I tried in my second attempt). Also, your code doesn't seem to handle (discard) file extension - that's why I tried to use AWK (in addition to being more familiar with it and it looks nicer IMHO). Could you suggest changes in your code to handle the above-mentioned requirements?

Comment: It looks like his file has more than one field split by periods. So you would need to use `while IFS=. read file extra` and then `printf "%s " $file; base64 -d <<<$file; echo` or something like that in the loop to get the right output.